# Azure B2C Bespoke login page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

**I there a way to make a completely bespoke login page for Azure B2C users?**

AWS Cognito offers [an SDK](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/) for developers to write completely bespoke login frontend sites. I'm looking for a way to do the same as this in Azure. I want to have control over the whole UI not just the HTML template for the login page. This means that I either need to have a JS library which has a `login(username, password)` type method, or some kind of API I can call directly to do this.

I would expect to find these kind of methods in the [msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser) library but it doesn't look like they are there. Is there a way I can call login from my own bespoke page or is it solely through the azure curated UI? I am only interested in local azure accounts not social or federated login.

What I'm **not** looking for:

- [Ui customisation for azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)
- [iframe embedding the UI into an existing site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

Answer (score 1):

There is no custom login endpoint in B2C.

Calling the authorize endpoint pops up the B2C login screen.

[ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) might meet your needs but it's being deprecated and not recommended.

Comment: I think you're right this might do what I'm after. I couldn't see anywhere in the docs to say its deprecated, where did you see that? Based on that doc however it seemed to suggest that apps would internally store the raw credentials to get new tokens which doesnt sound right, especially when there is a refresh token returned. If it does require storing credentials in browser I think ill find something else.

Comment: https://oauth.net/2.1/

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, azure B2C [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition) is what you are looking for. Keep in mind that it's advised to use it only for complex scenarios as the learning curve of it is somewhat high and its development can easily become hard to maintain.

Here you can find some auxiliary documentation that might be of help:

- [Azure AD B2C - Samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples)
- <3 [“Hello World and Then Some” with Azure Active Directory B2C Custom Policies](https://training.atmosera.com/hello-world-and-then-some-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-policies-part-1-introduction/)
- [Configure authentication in a sample single page application by using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app)

Comment: I had a read through these but couldnt find anywhere where it talked about building custom login screens. Do you have a specific custom policy in mind?

Comment: Yeah, I got your question wrong. Please go with @rbrayb inputs.